# How do I drop DataFrame rows with missing values?

Tags: dataframe, julia

E.g. if the original example were

```
│ Row │ a       │ b       │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1       │ missing │
│ 2   │ 2       │ 2       │
│ 3   │ missing │ 3       │
│ 4   │ 4       │ 4       │
```

And I want:

```
│ Row │ a │ b       │
├─────┼───┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ missing │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 2       │
│ 3   │ 4 │ 4       │
```

Is there a nice function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [in the docs](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.dropmissing!). In this case, it would be:

`dropmissing(df, :a)`